Could the IBM PC's Binary Synchronous Adapter be used for asynchronous RS-232?
For the IBM PC, IBM offered three different RS-232 adapters:

IBM Asynchronous Communications Adapter featuring an 8250 UART for asynchronous RS-232 at up to 9600 baud, 5 to 8 data bits, 1, 1.5 or 2 stop bits, and an optional parity bit, with a 25-pin D-shell connector offering either RS-232C or 20 mA current loop (selectable by jumper)
IBM Binary Synchronous Communications (BSC) Adapter featuring an Intel 8251A USART offering synchronous RS-232 at up to 9600 bits per second, also with a 25-pin D-shell connector
IBM Synchronous Data Link Control (SDLC)
Communications Adapter featuring an Intel 8273 SDLC Protocol Controller operating at up to 9600 bits per a second, also with a RS-232C 25-pin D-shell connector

(1) was by the far the most common; (2) and (3) were significantly rarer, primarily used if you needed to integrate with mainframe systems, especially IBM's.
The 8251A was a USART, and as such supported both synchronous and asynchronous RS-232; historically, there were a number of machines and adapter cards which had an 8251A USART but used it near exclusively in asynchronous mode – if one only needed asynchronous, the 8251A was more expensive than the 8250, yet nonetheless some vendors chose it over the 8250 for various reasons.
Anyway, here's my question: could you use the BSC adapter for asynchronous RS-232 too? The 8251A chip itself supports it, but IBM's adapter manual never mentions it. Is that because IBM didn't want to officially support that mode of operation even though it worked? Or is the circuitry on the BSC adapter card configured in such a way that it can't actually be used in asynchronous mode even if the 8251A was programmed for it?

Do you mean "support" as in "the OS and BIOS supported it" or as in "if you directly programmed the 8251A, it worked"? And chances are that if someone bought a BSC card, they needed it exactly for one purpose, and didn't play around with it.

I don’t believe the BIOS or PC-DOS had any support for the BSC adapter. It might have come with a driver TSR. But I was just asking if you put the 8251A in async mode by programming its registers, would that have worked.

@SimonKissane For the later: Yes. I can when given an appropriate clock source.

There are three main chips onboard the BSC adapter - 8251 USART, 8255 PPI (parallel port), and 8353 PIT (timer).
The block diagram explains that it's possible to use the PPI to select from where the USART transmit and receive clocks come from. They can come from the RS-232 connector interface, or from the PIT channel 0.
The manual says the PIT channel 0 is not used for synchronous operation.
However it seems that it can be used for asynchronous operation, by programming the timer channel 0 to provide suitable internal clock and then enabling the internal clock to the USART transmit and receive clocks.

And another minor point is that SYNDET/BRKDET is output only in asynchronous mode, but can be input in synchronous mode, but this pin is not actually wired according to the schematic, so there's no danger here. Besides that and the clocks, and don't see anything that could possibly wrong, but one would need a readl card to try it out...
